# Syntax error when comparing DateTime in C# to DateTime in Access

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I've tried several ways to make this work, but I keep getting the same error. I'm trying to delete a row in tblList where the column lisDate (whose type is DateTime) equals a date (without the time).
Assuming the date is 14/07/2012 (14th of July, 2012), and dbConnection is an open OleDbConnection:

```
string dt = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", 14, 07, 2012);
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM tblList WHERE CAST(lisDate as DATE) = #" + dt + "#", dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This gives the following error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CAST(lisDate as DATE) = #14/07/2012#'.

This may be a silly question because I've never compared DateTime values before, but I would appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: what rdbms you are using? sql server 2005, sql server 2008,sql server 2012, mysql, oracle, db2? what ? :D

Comment: Have you seen the output of what happens when you do a `CAST(lisDate as DATE)`? Maybe that output does not match what you have inside the `dt`. If so, then you will want to format your `dt` to match the same date format.

Comment: You have a syntax error, you need to figure out the correct syntax, before you worry about how to generate the synax from a .NET `DateTime` reference.

Comment: Part of your problem is that you are treating datetime data as a string which is what is causing you trouble.  If you would use a DateTime variable and a DateTime parameter then you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Access handy, but in SQL that code you have case an error. I'd try something like this as your query string:

```
"delete from tbllist where
cast(lisDate as varchar(9)) = '" +dt +"'"
```

actually, better would be:

```
"delete from tbllist
where datepart(mm,lisDate) = '07' and
datepart(dd,lisDate) = '14' and
datepart(yy,lisDate = '2012'  -- obviously cancatinating in your values
```

Comment: HOW will this fix the OP problem? The guy need to delete something from `tblList` with a WHERE clause. WHERE is your *WHERE* clause?

Comment: answer was sent before I finished. slip of the fingers, bro

Answer (score 0):

Try using a parameter, which will provide an implicit date conversion:

```
        string dt = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", 14, 07, 2012);
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM tblList WHERE lisDate = [pDate]", dbConnection);
        OleDbParameter dateParm = command.Parameters.Add("pDate", OleDbType.Date);
        dateParm.Value = dt;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**REVISION:**

A more complete solution that incorporates Chris Dunaway's incisive comment for supporting both dates and times follows:

```
    void DeleteByDate()
    {
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                dbConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                dbConnection.Open();
                string dt = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", 14, 07, 2012);
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM tblList WHERE lisDate = [pDate]", dbConnection))
                {
                    OleDbParameter dateParm = command.Parameters.Add("pDate", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp);
                    dateParm.Value = dt;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code uses a string with a date type parameter.  Perhaps a DateTime variable would be more appropriate?

Comment: Perhaps, but the example shows a date value and I presume the implicit conversion would handle it properly. But to presume is not to know, so I will make a test and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks Chris, see the revised solution.

Comment: This definitely seems better, but there's a strange error:
No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: Hmmm. I tested this solution in Access. Does your table contain a field called "lisDate"?